Is building the universes for (∞-)toposes (of subsets of data points) a categorical generalization of theory induction in ML and algorithm?
I am reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07004 "All (∞,1)-toposes have strict univalent universes" and I am thinking about its applications to the machine learning.
Can we recast the theoretical flow in this article as following algorithmic sketch:

we start with the cloud of data points (e.g. pixel RGB values of image) and we consider the subsets of this cloud. E.g. there can be preliminary clustering of data points or image segmentation so that some subset of data points can be attributed to some possible image that is represented by respective part of image. The collection of such subsets may form topos;
we apply the machinery of the referenced article to construct object U in this topos and the morphism U~->U so, that each subset is mapped into U. This is the universe of this topos which is constructed by the quite involved procedure of the referenced article;
we can try to read the type theory from the universe U (e.g. U is collection of specific elements and we can assign type to each element or structure of elements). This is the way to discover/induce the theory whose one of the interpretations is out initial data cloud.
having the theory we can sample new data points according to this theory or use the theory to answer different questions about data (e.g. collection of objects in the picture and the associations among those objects - i.e. semantics of the picture)

There are some remote approaches to such theory induction - like ILP (Inductive Logic Programming) and higher-order program induction (e.g. https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/activities/programinduction/)
My question is - is the construction of universe in some topos (of subsets of data points) really applicable in the machine learning for the theory induction/discovery from data. And what would be more or less specific algorithmical recast of this procedure (essentially - what would be algorithm of theory discovery from data if we follow the reference article)? And is this the example how category theory research can provide the scheme for the constructio of algorithms in machine learning?
Of course, toposes, universes and type theories are crisp objects. But I guess - there can be fuzzy category theory and fuzzy toposes or probabilistic toposes and then there is https://www.amazon.com/Shape-Theory-Categorical-Approximation-Mathematics/dp/048646623X as well. So - crisp approach could be quite fruitful starting point.
Why HoTT? Of course, we can try to do this for FOL, HOL, but if there are work that covers the most expressible formalism, the it can be wise to take precisely it.
Maybe such application to machine learning is not only valuable in itself, but it can ground the abstract thinking in some reality and that can be quite helpful for some of the poeple who are desperate for the intuition and who can be helped by providing such intuition or practical example.
